# Preview material texture defferent than render

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, displacement

I'm having problems with making realistic texture. Following *Blender Guru* tutorial from a year ago I made a plane with custom material using nodes and few images from *CrazyBump*.

For some reason internal material preview shows my material exactly how I want it, but render is different (both full render [F12] and render preview). There is some data "getting trough" because the plane have a different colour but that's it.

[image: correct material on the right, different preview]
I tried manipulating the nodes, subdividing a plane but nothing seems to work.

Is that just a wrong workflow, or maybe a bug? Am I missing something? 
Would appreciate any help. :)

here's a file:

[image]

Comment: The textures are not included in your blend file... so nothing is visible. Can you pack them in the file (file/external data/automatically...) ? Also, please use this site to upload : http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Fixed it ? You mean the file or your problem ?

Comment: No - I meant the link to the file with attached textures - this time..

Comment: OK... simply add an input node "Texture coordinate", then link the "generated" slot of it (as you dont have uv map) to ALL the textures inputs (the 4)

Comment: WOW. Thank you. So the set up was ok, but I DID miss the coordinates of the texture. I have to read more about it. Thanks again!